# Trim string after character '?' getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, substring, slice, getelementsbyclassname

Tidying URLs displaying in a dynamically populated list; have managed to remove full domain from beginning but now need to trim all characters after '?' for all results.  getElementsByClassName is not working for me, and I cannot figure out why.

[CodePen Snippet](https://codepen.io/LivelyDev/pen/mwrora)

Using:

```
var oldURL = "some?text";
// var oldURL = document.getElementsByClassName("slimBreadcrumb");
oldURL = oldURL.substring(0, oldURL.indexOf("?"));
document.write(oldURL);
```

and:

```
var styleBreadcrumb = document.getElementsByClassName("slimBreadcrumb");
  for (var i = 0; i < styleBreadcrumb.length; i++) {
    var str = styleBreadcrumb[i].innerHTML;
    var text = str
      .replace(/http:|https:/, "")
      .replace(/\/\//g, "")
      .replace("www.google.com/", "")
      .replace(/\//g, " > ")
      .replace(/-/g, " ");
    styleBreadcrumb[i].innerHTML = text;
  }
```

on:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com/apples/before?after-asdfstrwggs-adf?fadsfad</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">http://www.google.com/apples/oranges/peaches/pears</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">https://www.google.com/apples/oranges/peaches/pears</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">http://www.google.com/apples/oranges/peaches/pears-watermelons-apricots</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">http://www.google.com/apples/before?after-asdfstrwggs-adf?fadsfad</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: "*… getElementsByClassName is not working for me*" in what way? What error do you get? There is no regular expression in your sequence of replaces that attempts to replace "?" and following characters. I think `.replace(/\?.*$/,'')` should go close.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
var styleBreadcrumb = document.getElementsByClassName("slimBreadcrumb");

for (var i = 0; i < styleBreadcrumb.length; i++) {
  var str = styleBreadcrumb[i].innerText.trim();
  var text = str
    .replace(/http:|https:/, "")
    .replace(/\/\//g, "")
    .replace("www.google.com/", "")
    .replace(/\//g, " > ")
    .replace(/-/g, " ");
  text = text.split('?')[0];
  styleBreadcrumb[i].innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com/apples/before?after-asdfstrwggs-adf?fadsfad</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">http://www.google.com/apples/oranges/peaches/pears</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">https://www.google.com/apples/oranges/peaches/pears</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">http://www.google.com/apples/oranges/peaches/pears-watermelons-apricots</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="slimBreadcrumb" href="#">http://www.google.com/apples/before?after-asdfstrwggs-adf?fadsfad</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it works perfectly - I knew I'd made a muppet error, just couldn't see it for the trees.